# How do reverse the indexing order of a sub-loop every other pass?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2 dimensional array (10x10) that represents x & y positions. I'm writing a script that goes to each position, does some stuff, then moves to the next position.

The most efficient way would be to start in one corner, scan at a constant x value (moving through y values), then at the end of all of the y values, moves over one x value and moves through y values in reverse order. Kind of like a snake pattern if that makes sense.

My loop currently looks something like this:

```
for x in x_values: 
     for y in y_values: 
          do_something()
          move to y + 1
     move to x + 1
     move back to first y value
```

As you can see, I'm completing a column (in y), advancing one x value, then rewinding back to the first y value. I'd like to run the y values in reverse for even number x values.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: You could e. g. use `flip` to create an array view mirrored along y-axis. Then you can iterate over the original array or the mirrored one depending on x position.

Comment: _The most efficient way would be to start in one corner_ If you're controlling some kind of physical device that has to actually travel to each location, like a CNC router etching a pattern onto a piece of wood, then this would be efficient.  But if you're just accessing memory addresses, I don't see why this matters.

Comment: Iteration like this is more efficient when working with a list of lists,  not a numpy array.  Lists can be accessed in reverse with `x[::-1]` indexing.  That `-1` step applies to arrays and `range` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```
for x in x_values:
    for y in y_values:
        do_something()
    y_values.reverse()
```

After each iteration over `y_values` ​​, `y_values` ​​is reversed.